# Kick command isn't working after I mention a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I just coded a kick command. But after I mention a user, the bot doesn't send any messages and it doesn't kick the member.

This is the code:

```js
if (message.content==config.prefix+"kick"){
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send({ content: "**You need to mention someone to kick!**" })
        const kickMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args);
        const kickReason = args.slice(1).join(" ") || "No reason identified";
        if(!message.members.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send({ content: "**You don't have permissions to kick a member...**" })
        if(!message.guild.me.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send({ content: "**I don't have permissions to kick a member...**" })
        
        if(!kickMember.kickable) return message.channel.send({ content: "**This member isn't kickable, you need to lower their roles first!**" })
        
        kickMember.kick({ reason: kickReason })
        const kickEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${kickMember} has been kicked!`)
        .setDescription(`Reason: ${kickReason}`)
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [kickEmbed] })
    }
```

What can I do?

Comment: Do you get any errors after using the command? If yes, can you edit it in your question please

Comment: After I used the command, I don't get any errors in the terminal.

Comment: Do you have the message content intent? You should log the message so you know it executed.

Comment: I turned the message content intent on, but how do I log it?